# How to add custom AngularJS directives to html validator in Netbeans 7.4 IDE?

Tags: angularjs, netbeans

I recently switched to Netbeans 7.4 IDE from Eclipse and would like to know how to add custom Angular directives to html validator.

If you add something like this to your html file:

```
<div>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

an error will be shown stating:

```
"Element "my-directive" not allowed as child of element "div" in this context."
```

I could just disable "elements" attribute in html validator to avoid this error but I'd rather not since it will suppress real errors.

Comment: what would example of real error be?

Comment: If you want to stay at Netbeans this would not help, but in PhpStorm (or WebStorm) you are able to add node names to an ignore list, for html validation.

Answer (score 2):

You can either declare a custom namespace for your directives, see http://forums.netbeans.org/post-59359.html or define custom tags: http://wiki.netbeans.org/CustomTagActions